# Renaming y axis ticks ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I create the following plot: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZJPp.png)

These ticks are generated automatically.

I'd like to rename the Y axis ticks with :
80000 to 1:20:000,
84000 to 1:24:000,
88000 to 1:28:000,
92000 to 1:32:000

This is my code:

```
seby_time<-ggplot(tempi_seb,aes(lap,milliseconds),color=position) + 
geom_point() +
geom_line(color="red")
```

I tried varius solutions but no one work.

Geom_line() or other type of "line functions" are required for this job.

Thanks

Comment: See https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/faq-axes.html#label-formatting-and-customization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `scale_y_continuous`. Here is a minimal example

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Sepal.Length)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(5, 7), labels = c("5.0", "7.0"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ,you give me a really big help!